Cannot log out of Copilot in PhpStorm
I accidentally logged into the wrong account when setting up GitHub's Copilot in PhpStorm.

I tried uninstalling the plugin and restarting.
I tried selecting a different GitHub account in the Copilot settings.
Other posts have suggested there is a logout button/link in the Copilot settings, but that is not in my PhpStorm 2024.3.1.1 Copilot settings.

How do I disconnect the wrong GitHub account so I can use the one I'm actually paying for Copilot on?

I'm not using Copilot so cannot help directly. But I can suggest to try the following (in case you are still unable to locate the log out button): 1) Exit the IDE; 2) Go to the folder where the IDE-wide settings are stored (see this link for details; 3) go into options folder and look for a config file that can be related to copilot (or perhaps GitHub). It should be a XML file -- see if you can spot the login there. If anything -- try deleting the file.

This may not work that well if you are using the bundled plugin to sync your IDE settings to the cloud (JetBrains account). If it's the case -- try disabling such sync first (and restart the IDE) ... or check for the same files in a settingsSync folder there (in addition to the aforementioned options one).

None of that worked. There also isn't a settingsSync file or folder anywhere on my Mac. However, I did notice that despite the fact that a popup says I'm logged into Github, it was apparently fake news. I noticed the login link in the settings and logged into the correct account. When I did this, it also displayed a logout link I could use.
